# Use delimited text Vector data provider in QGIS 3.0 Processing Algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I am writing a Processing Algorithm based on [this template](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/). Can I populate the `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink` from a `delimitedtext provider` in a similar fashion to the `iface.addVectorLayer()` (i.e. the following code snippet) ?

```
uri = ('file:///{}?'
       'type=regexp'
       '&delimiter={}'
       '&skipLines={}'
       '&useHeader=No'
       '&trimFields=Yes'
       '&xField=field_11'
       '&yField=field_12'
       '&crs={}'
       '&spatialIndex=Yes'
       '&subsetIndex=no'
       '&watchFile=Yes').format(myFile,
                                myRe,
                                countSkips(myFile),
                                myCrs)

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri, 'MY LAYER',  'delimitedtext')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use feature sink parameters for a hard-coded layer like this. Just load it direct via

```
vl=QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'MY LAYER',  'delimitedtext')
```

Comment: Thanks, so based on the mentioned template, how should I define my output? `QgsVectorLayer` directly?

Comment: I've tried to define my output as `QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination` (rather than `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer`) then set `vl = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)` but I can't make it work.

Comment: I've made it [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280520/let-qgis-3-0-processing-algorithm-output-a-vectorlayer-loaded-via-the-delimited) as my problem is now how to get my `Algorithm` return this `vl`.