# Let QGIS 3.0 Processing algorithm output a VectorLayer loaded via the delimited text provider

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, qgis-3

Following up on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280330/use-delimited-text-vector-data-provider-in-qgis-3-0-processing-algorithm), I need to be able to setup the `QgsVectorLayer` loaded via the `delimitedtext` `provider` as my algorithm output.

Note that I am still working from [this template](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).
For lack of a better idea, I have defined (in `initAlgorithm`) the output like so:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination(
        self.OUTPUT,
        self.tr('Output'),
        type = QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry
    )
)
```

And my Algorithm currently looks like this:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    ## Define some parameters and functions to handle the loaded file.

    # Getting parameters values to local variables
    crs = self.parameterAsCrs(parameters, self.CRS, context)
    inputFile = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.FILEIN, context)
    ver = self.parameterAsEnum(parameters, self.VERSION, context)

    dest_id = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUPUT, context)

    uri = ('file:///{}?'
              'type=regexp'
              '&delimiter={}'
              '&skipLines={}'
              '&useHeader=No'
              '&trimFields=Yes'
              '&xField={}'
              '&yField={}'
              '&crs={}'
              '&spatialIndex=Yes'
              '&subsetIndex=no'
              '&watchFile=Yes').format(inputFile,
                                       regex,
                                       skips,
                                       'Easting',
                                       'Northing',
                                       crs.geographicCrsAuthId())

    vl = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'MY_LAYER',  'delimitedtext')

    # Setup Fields Aliases
    for idx, alias in enumerate(myFields):
        try:
            vl.setFieldAlias(idx, alias)
        except:
            continue

    return {'MY_LAYER': dest_id}
```

The `return` line is where the crash happens but I'm running out of ideas: by comparison with the template where `self.parameterAsSink()` returned a tuple `(sink, dest_id)`, I'm guessing the `self.parameterAsOutputLayer()` returns the `dest_id`.
Then I try to return the created layer `vl` and associate it with the `dest_id`, again, by analogy with the template.

I am stuck here as Qgis (3.0.2) crashes (right at the `return` line, every line of code gets executed without problem) every time I try to run this current code (but I can make it work fine as a standalone script from the Python Console...)

I have tried the following variations and all lead to invariable crashing:
`return 'MY_LAYER'`
`return {vl: dest_id}`
`return {dest_id}`
`return dest_id`
`return vl`
`return`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your output here is effectively hard-coded, you don't need to define it as a input parameter. Instead declare it as an output that your algorithm generates:

```
self.addOutput(
    QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer(
        self.OUTPUT,
        self.tr('Output'),
        type = QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry)
)
```

Then, in your processAlgorithm method (simplified to just the relevant bits):

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    crs = self.parameterAsCrs(parameters, self.CRS, context)
    inputFile = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.FILEIN, context)

    uri = ('file:///{}?'
           'type=regexp'
           '&delimiter={}'
           '&skipLines={}'
           '&useHeader=No'
           '&trimFields=Yes'
           '&xField={}'
           '&yField={}'
           '&crs={}'
           '&spatialIndex=Yes'
           '&subsetIndex=no'
           '&watchFile=Yes').format(inputFile,
                                    regex,
                                    skips,
                                    'Easting',
                                    'Northing',
                                    crs.geographicCrsAuthId())

    vl = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'MY_LAYER', 'delimitedtext')

    return {self.OUTPUT: vl}
```

Comment: I have no doubt the answer is correct, although, interestingly, my script still get QGIS to crash every single time. I am loading a 46MB text file that contains a bit less than 582k points but memory shouldn't be a problem as a standalone script works fine every time.

Comment: I've currently resorted to parse the file manually and went back to the original template with a `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink`. This is actually cleaner as I am able to have proper names for `Fields` and icing on the cake, it's even a little faster than the `delimitedtext` provider...

Comment: Just a comment for anyone using this solution. `inputFile` needs to be specified as a `QgsProcessingParameterFile` parameter in `initAlgorithm` for this to work (e.g. `self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile(self.FILEIN, self.tr('Input file')))`.